# Is there a "blessed" Heroku way to set up an SSLProxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku, reverse-proxy

I'm building a social site in which all content is served over SSL. I'd like to be able to paste:

```
http://i.imgur.com/W15FE.jpg
```

and have the app serve up something like

```
https://myproxy.com/i.imgur.com/W15FE.jpg
```

thus avoiding the warnings regarding insecure content.

I'm open to a better approach, but I hope link the user back to the original image/site with a credit, etc and with my current understanding, would prefer not to avoid downloading and hosting the image myself.

Answer (score 0):

#### Same Host

You can force a redirection to SSL in ApplicationController. First, you need to configure SSL for your Heroku application; [piggyback SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#piggyback_ssl_myappherokucom_and_myappherokuappcom_only) may be sufficient for your use case.

Next, configure your app to redirect to SSL in production. For example:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :redirect_to_https
  private
  def redirect_to_https
    redirect_to :protocol => "https://" unless ( request.ssl?  ||
                                                 request.local? )
  end
end
```

#### Remote Host

If you aren't hosting the files directly, you may need to redirect the browser with a route or controller action. For example, [using redirect_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) on a modified [request.url](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object).

Comment: [SSL Endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint) is the next generation SSL product from Heroku. It is recommended for securing custom domains, if that's necessary in this particular scenario.

Comment: I've got the force ssl set up just fine. I'm wondering about using some type of proxy to host external resources with an https environment under my control.